# Exporting SQL Server MDF and LDF database files

Tags: sql-server

How do I export a SQL Server 2000/2005 database to MDF/LDF files? I do not have access to detach the database nor do I have access to login to the database server to copy the files directly.

Comment: Do you have permission to run the backup command from the database server?

Comment: Yes I do, however the backup seems to only be able to be created on the server inside MSSQL\BACKUP\. I can't specify for it to write out to a location that I would be able access in order to copy the file to my machine.

Comment: You can specify a path to the backup command.  It would have to be some sort of network location that you can access from your machine.

Comment: I'll give that a try. I need to find out what network locations are available on that server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you run commands against the database from a query window? Do you know of a network path accessible to both you and the SQL Server instance? If so then you can issue the following query (instead of trying to coax some backup through the UI):

```
BACKUP DATABASE dbname TO DISK = '\\some_network_path_you\have_access_to\db.bak' 
  WITH COPY_ONLY, INIT;
```

`COPY_ONLY` is important so that you don't disrupt the production server's log chain.

Then you can copy that file and run `RESTORE DATABASE` wherever you like.

You *don't* want to somehow get access to the MDF / LDF files. For one, in order to copy those, you need to shut down the source SQL Server and detach them. This can lead to many bad things, but most importantly downtime on the production server, and the risk that if something should go wrong, you now have ZERO copies of your database.

Answer (score 0):

Then you request that your dba provide the data to you.

Comment: I put in a request but the DBA hasn't been able to get around to it. I was really hoping there was something I could do on my end to speed things up.